# ACTION_SHUTDOWN not working

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using a simple Broadcast Receiver to send sms on devices shut down.

I've tried it on different phones, it works well on two of them but not on my samsung galaxy S2 and on my samsung Galaxy Xcover.

I also tried with the QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF action, but nothing.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you trying to reboot or poweroff? I am not sure sending sms will work, because all foreground apps will be paused, because the system is shutting down. Are

Comment: Hi Durairaj P, I'm trying to send SMS when the phone is turned off. What I don't get, is why it's working on two of my phones but not on my Xcover.